# Are there any non-trivial convergent sequences in the maximal ideal space of the measure algebra?

Tags: gn.general-topology, harmonic-analysis, limits-and-convergence, banach-algebras, gelfand-duality

Consider the measures on the circle, $M(\mathbb T)$, endowed with the convolution product which makes it a unital Banach algebra under the total variation norm. Denote by $\Delta$ the maximal ideal space of $M(\mathbb T)$. This space is quite large–recently it was shown that $\Delta$ [is non-separable](https://projecteuclid.org/euclid.afm/1485802756), for example. It also has many copies of $\beta \mathbb N$, yet it is not extremely disconnected, however, in certain sense, it is not too far from being so.

Extremely disconnected spaces do not have injective convergent sequences, again $\beta \mathbb N$ serves a paradigm example.

> Does $\Delta$ have any injective convergent sequences?

I have some evidence that it should not be the case but I am unable to make it into a proof. Maybe this follows from some known facts anyway?

Comment: I think [this](https://digitalcommons.lsu.edu/cgi/viewcontent.cgi?referer=&httpsredir=1&article=1960&context=gradschool_disstheses) Ph.D. thesis of J. Taylor might be of use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Norbert is right (see the paper *[The Structure of Convolution Measure Algebras)](http://The%20Structure%20of%20Convolution%20Measure%20Algebras)*. Actually, I had known the result but it didn't occur to me that it would have solved the problem.

The maximal ideal space of $M(\mathbb T)$ contains an analytic disk, which in particular, is a homeomorphic copy of $\mathbb D$, so there are plenty of convergent sequences therein.